# Rails session dependent constants

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to figure out how to elegantly expose an external API client to models in my rails app which is dependent on the current session. Here's a snippet of my ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

private
  def user_api
    @api ||= HollerAPI.new(current_user.jwt, :user) if current_user
  end
end
```

However this `user_api` is not accessible to models. Instead it would be awesome if I could define a constant such as `USER_API` and then it's accessible everywhere in the application. Is there a way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

The model world and the controller world are kept separate. You must bridge this gap carefully to avoid causing total chaos where data from one request related to a particular user bleeds over into another request.

If you need to do something in a model with an API configured by the controller, let the controller assume control:

```
@model = SomeModel.find(...)

user_api.post_model(@model)
```

Try to avoid making models too clever or smart. That can lead to wildly unpredictable side-effects that are very hard to test.

If you absolutely must provide a bridge to your models, add a property to your model you can use to populate this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accesssor :user_api
end
```

Then you can populate this via the controller and use it within the model:

```
@model = MyModel.find(...)
@model.user_api = user_api
```

That bridges the gap:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def do_stuff_with_api
    user_api.post_model(self)
  end
end
```

Remember that the primary function of the controller in an MVC world is to directly control things. Giving models too much autonomy confuses the concerns.

Comment: The problem with the first suggestion is that I'm now creating a client library that explicitly accepts arguments specific to this application.

Comment: Unless the model can figure out what API credentials it's supposed to use, you really need to leave this up to the controller. It's possible to propagate things down to the model via things like thread-local variables but this is extremely risky.